# flexigrid - how to change colmodel

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, flexigrid

I'm using flexigrid to display some data from server via ajax. The thing is that I can't tell beforehand which columns are going to be displayed.

How can I set the colModel based on the data retrieved?

In the ajax file I added a "cols" key to the json that enumerates the columns that are found in the row.cell key:

```
{
    "page": "1",
    "total": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Some data"
            }
        }
    ],
    "cols": [
        "id",
        "name"
    ]
}
```

And in populate() I do this:

```
//ajax success
p.colModel = {};
var colModelItem = new Array();
for(var col in data.cols)
{
        colModelItem.push({
                "display": data.cols[col],
                "name": data.cols[col],
                "width": 80,
                "sortable": true,
                "align": "center"
                });
}
p.colModel = colModelItem;

//g.addData(data);
```

After that I tried to use the functionality that creates the headers but with no success.

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem, dynamic columns, i solved with an workaround:

Creating an wraper div, like that:

```
    $("#searchResults").empty();
    $("#searchResults").append($("<div>").attr("id", "flexiGridHack"));
```

And instead of using the original Div, you use the new Div.

With Regards,

Comment: Umm, shouldn't you use `.wrapAll()`?